# CPQ - Bundle Configuration using Sections Option Layout Not Acting as Expected

Tags: lightning, cpq, product

We have built a Bundled Product in salesforce. We are using the sections option layout. The first criteria within the bundle (DnA or Suite) should allow the user the ability to select one of the products within that section. But when we go to add the product when the configurator for the bundle opens one option is grayed out. See screenshot below:

[image]

This is controlled by the features in the bundle product configuration. We created the same product using the Wizard option layout. With the Wizard option that feature works as expected. Neither option is grayed out. See screenshot below of the Wizard Option Layout:

[image]

Below are the features for the Sections Option Layout. These features are setup exactly the same for the Wizard Option Layout:

[image]

What could be causing this problem. I have rebuilt the bundle 3 times and keep having the same issue.

Any direction on how to correct this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct this by adjusting the Features.